# Return arguments to an other function

Tags: php

When there is inheritance we can do this:

```
class Demo
{    
    public function doStuff(Form $form, Request $request)
    {     
        parent::doStuff($form, $request);
    }

}
```

Is there a way to inject these same parameter in a funciton that is not a parent, ie:

```
//...
MyRandomClass::doStuff($form, $request);
//...
```

If yes, what is the synthax?

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyRandomClass::doStuff($form, $request);
```

will just work (assuming MyRandomClass has been included/required in the context of this line) if the function doStuff() is defined as "public static".

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to inject these same parameter in a funciton that is
>   not a parent

do you mean to say, you want to pass the same parameter values inside of another function of the same name in some other class.

```
public function doStuff(Form $form, Request $request)
{     
    parent::doStuff($form, $request);
    MyRandomClass::doStuff($form, $request);
}
```

above code will pass the parameter values to `MyRandomClass::dostuff()` method too. remember that the method should be static otherwise it won't work.